# Codecademy Hurricane

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at Codecademy and I'm currently doing this Hurricane Analysis project. The question I'm stuck on requires me to convert a string (such as "1.76B") and convert it to a real number.

I've tried parsing the string, but can't figure out how to add and convert the B part and add it to the float.

```py
def convert_damages(damages):
  for damage in damages:
    if damage[-1] == 'B':
      split_damages = damage.split('B')

    elif damage[-1] == 'M':
      split_damages = damage.split('M')

    else:
      return
```

So if I have a list containing something like 1.76M, 2.35B and 3.11M it should return something like 1760000, 2350000000, 3110000

Comment: Your code reads `for damage in damages` implying that `damages` is a list of strings, but you mention you want to pass `"1.76M"` as input to your function. Should your function accept a list of strings or a single string?

Comment: Where is your split string being converted to a float? You could just remove the period as well as the letter, append the correct number of zeroes, then convert that to a number.

Comment: sorry, confused you there. What i meant for the last part is that should've been a list and if 1.76 was part of that it should be returned as 1760000

Comment: I edited the post now so it should be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a dictionary to hold the conversion factors rather than conditionals

```
def convert_damages(damages):
  " convert damages to a number using following steps "

  # Table (dictionary) of conversion lookups
  # i.e. conversion_factors['B'] = 10^9, conversion_factors['K']  = 10^3, etc.
  conversion_factors = {'B': 1E9,'K': 1E3, 'M': 1E6}

  # Get the numeric part of string
  num_string = damages[:-1] # number part is everything but last character

  # get the factor part of string (last character)
  factor = damages[-1]   # last character is conversion

  new_number = float(num_string) * conversion_factors[factor]

  return new_number
```

Test

```
for num in ['1.76B', '1.76K', '1.76M']:
  print(num, ' => ', convert_damages(num))
```

Output

```
1.76B  =>  1760000000.0
1.76K  =>  1760.0
1.76M  =>  1760000.0
```

Comment: I would think `B` means "billion" so the factor would be `1,000,000,000` or `1e9`.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid--you convinced me.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

1. Make sure that every case returns something - I've added a `return` at the end.
2. Note that `split` returns a list; If you want the first element, take it with `[0]`.
3. `split` returns a list of strings, but you can convert your string to a `float` by calling `float(the_string)`.
4. Finally, don't forget to multiply by 10 to the relevant power (M is 6 and B is 9 where I come from; change yours appropriately).

The function is as follows:

```
def convert_damages(damages):
    for damage in damages:
        if damage[-1] == 'B':
            split_damages = float(damage.split('B')[0]) * (10 ** 9)

        elif damage[-1] == 'M':
            split_damages = float(damage.split('M')[0]) * (10 ** 6)

        else:
            return
    return split_damages
```

Good luck!

Comment: This will only return the last damage in the list. The name `split_damages` implies a list but you are using it as a single `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to help you with this. The first step is creating a pattern that matches your expected string. You should match one or more digits, followed by 0 or 1 period, and then 1 or more digits. Finally, you want some factor at the end of your string. Since you only mentioned M and B, that's all I've included here. The regex pattern used would be `^(\d+(\.?\d+)?)([MB])$`.

Explanation of the pattern:

1. `^` Matches the start of the string
2. `(\d+(\.?\d+)?)` Matches one or more digits followed by (optionally) a decimal and one or more digits.
3. `([MB])` Matches `M` or `B` literally.
4. `$` Matches end of the string

Because of how our pattern is set up, `match.group(0)` will be the entire match (this is always true). `match.group(1)` will be the full number. `match.group(2)` will be either empty or the decimal point and additional numbers. Note that group 2 is inside group 1 (look at the parenthesis) so we don't need to access group 2 at all. The entire number is in group 1. `match.group(3)` will be the letter at the end of the string, if it is M or B.

Finally, we need some kind of map between the alphabetic factor (M or B) and the numeric factor (1 million or 1 billion). A dictionary is perfect for this. We multiply the number found in `match.group(1)` with the numerical factor, and that is our result.

```py
import re


def convert_damage(damage):
  damage_pattern = re.compile(r"^(\d+(\.?\d+)?)([MB])$")
  match = damage_pattern.match(damage)
  if match is None:
    print(f"The provided damage '{damage}' is not in the appropriate format.")
    return
  number = float(match.group(1))   # This is the number 
  factor = match.group(3)   # This is the factor string (M or B)
  factor_map = {"M": 1e6, "B": 1e9}
  actual_damage = number * factor_map[factor]
  return actual_damage

def convert_damages(damages):
  output = []
  for damage in damages:
    output.append(convert_damage(damage))
  return output

### Converting single damages
d1 = "1.76M"
print(f"{d1} -> {convert_damage(d1)}")
d2 = "3.52B"
print(f"{d2} -> {convert_damage(d2)}")


### Converting a list of damages
tests = [d1, d2, "6B", "1..5M", "0.2B"]
results = convert_damages(tests)
for damage_str, damage_num in zip(tests, results):
    print(f"{damage_str} -> {damage_num}")
```

Output:

```
1.76M -> 1760000.0
3.52B -> 3520000000.0
The provided damage '1..5M' is not in the appropriate format.
1.76M -> 1760000.0
3.52B -> 3520000000.0
6B -> 6000000000.0
1..5M -> None
0.2B -> 200000000.0
```